# Proof that gravitational force is conservative

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy, conservative-field

It is a well accepted fact that gravitational force is conservative in nature, i.e, the work done on an object in gravitational field is independent of the path taken.

To prove the above statement, I want to have

1. An **intuitive** proof based on understanding and thought experiments.
2. A **formal and rigorous** mathematical proof.
3. Can the **same logic be *extended*** to prove the conservative nature of other forces as well?

Comment: Please ask a conceptual question.

Comment: This is covered in litearlly every introductory physics textbook

Comment: @AfterShave, can you please share the source

Comment: Just calculate the curl and show it's zero.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force